# Timeout expired. XAF .Net6 Winforms Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, xaf

I am troubleshooting why so many sessions are open in SQL Server with my XAF 23.1.6 EF Core 7.0.3 project.

In SSMS I ran

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id > 50 AND host_name = 'MYCOMPUTER'
ORDER BY last_request_end_time ASC
```

To see what sessions were open.

I created a new project from the wizard with standard security and ran it in the Visual Studio IDE whilst monitoring the sessions in SSMS.

It seems that the number of sessions only increases as I use the program.

For example if I open the Users View and then the Roles View the sessions increase. But the sessions do not decrease when I close these views.

How do I get XAF to close unneeded sessions?

The user experience is time out errors.

[Update]

The DbContext code is

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.DesignTime;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF.PermissionPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects;

public class MyAppContextInitializer : DbContextTypesInfoInitializerBase
{
    protected override DbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppEFCoreDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(";")
            .UseChangeTrackingProxies()
            .UseObjectSpaceLinkProxies();
        return new MyAppEFCoreDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

[TypesInfoInitializer(typeof(MyAppContextInitializer))]
public class MyAppEFCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppEFCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppEFCoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<ModelDifference> ModelDifferences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelDifferenceAspect> ModelDifferenceAspects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PermissionPolicyRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects.ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects.ApplicationUserLoginInfo> UserLoginInfos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasChangeTrackingStrategy(ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangingAndChangedNotificationsWithOriginalValues);
        modelBuilder.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.PreferFieldDuringConstruction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects.ApplicationUserLoginInfo>(
            b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(
                    nameof(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ISecurityUserLoginInfo.LoginProviderName),
                    nameof(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.ISecurityUserLoginInfo.ProviderUserKey))
                    .IsUnique();
            });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ModelDifference>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Aspects)
            .WithOne(t => t.Owner)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

[Update]

Demo project at [GitHub here](https://github.com/kgreed/MyXaf)

[Update]

I was able to repeat the issue with a simple console project that simply opened a dbcontext added a record and closed.
It appears that sessions are not closed until the program exits.

[Update]

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359813/ef-dbcontext-dispose-not-closing-the-connection) it appears I am on the wrong track investigating the number of open sessions to resolve why the application is timing out.

It turns out that in some of my code ( not the linked demo ) I have

Some of my code ( not in the sample ) is like the following;

```
public static void StartPurchaseOrderDetailView(XafApplication application, ActionBaseEventArgs e)
{
    var os = application.CreateObjectSpace(typeof(PurchaseOrder));
    var h = os.CreateObject<PurchaseOrder>();
    var detailView = application.CreateDetailView(os, h);
    // the following line was missing
    detailView.Closed += (sender, args) => ((DetailView)sender).ObjectSpace.Dispose();
    e.ShowViewParameters.CreatedView = detailView;
    e.ShowViewParameters.NewWindowTarget = NewWindowTarget.MdiChild;
    e.ShowViewParameters.TargetWindow = TargetWindow.NewWindow;
}
```

It makes sense that this is the problem.
I will know in the next few days wether the issue is fixed.

Comment: Probably the first place to look would be how your DbContext lifetime scope is being managed. Is is set up to be injected into code that is using it, and if so with what lifetime scope? Or using a factory, or newed up as it is needed? DbContexts should be short-lived and disposed, so no longer than a web request. I'm not familiar with XAF and "sessions" but if it's looking to wrap something like SignalR to facilitate push notifications to clients then you will need to be a bit more hands-on with managing a DbContext's lifetime.

Comment: XAF uses an EFObjectSpace class to manage the DbContext. I would have thought closing a View would close the EFObjectSpace and hence reduce the SQL Server sessions. But it appears not to.

Comment: can you provide model and/or controllers and/or view implementation details? you should deal with objectspace only.

Comment: ideally more insight will help, check this: XAF requires Multiple Active Result Sets in EF Core-based applications connected to a Microsoft SQL Server database. We do not recommend that you remove MultipleActiveResultSets=True; from the connection string or set the MultipleActiveResultSets parameter to false

Comment: I have MultipleActiveSets set to true.
I have linked a demo repository of a project made from the Dev Express wizard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359813/ef-dbcontext-dispose-not-closing-the-connection